# Angular - How to implement conditional statement in View Detail

Tags: angular

In my Angular12 I have:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  Current Status: <strong>{{employee?.current_status || 'N/A' }}</strong>
</div>
```

current_status can be:  Employed, Resigned, Inactive

Using if statement, I want to implement this:

```
<span class="badge bg-success">Employed</span>

<span class="badge bg-warning">Inactive</span>

<span class="badge bg-danger">Resigned</span>
```

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try ngswitch? https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<span *ngIf="employee.current_status === 'Employed'" class="badge bg-success">Employed</span>

<span *ngIf="employee.current_status === 'Resigned'" class="badge bg-warning">Inactive</span>

<span *ngIf="employee.current_status === 'Inactive'" class="badge bg-danger">Resigned</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a switch with a default:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="employee?.current_status" class="col-md-6">
  <span *ngSwitchDefault class="badge bg-success">Current Status: N/A</span>
  <span *ngSwitchCase="Employed" class="badge bg-success">Current Status: Employed</span>
  <span *ngSwitchCase="Inactive" class="badge bg-warning">Current Status: Inactive</span>
  <span *ngSwitchCase="Resigned" class="badge bg-danger">Current Status: Resigned</span>
</div>
```